# Mysql Query Optimization - Shared Query need to optimized

Tags: mysql

Please help me to optimize below Query -

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    al.displayName AS 'Brand',
    al.locationName AS 'Campus',
    pg.groupName AS 'School Phase',
    result.programName AS 'Grade',
    pc.categoryName AS 'Grade Category',
    result.batchName AS 'Intake',
    result.periodName AS 'Period',
    admission.id AS 'ADmission',
    result.stdName AS 'Student Name',
    usr.code AS 'Student Id',
    result.courseName AS 'Subject',
    result.courseVariant AS 'Subject Variant',
    cc.categoryName AS 'Subject Category',
    fac.printName AS 'Teacher',
    result.planPrintName AS 'Scheme',
    planRank.marksObtainedFrom AS 'Maximum Marks',
    planRank.gradeObtainedFrom AS 'Maximum Grade',
    planRank.obtainedMarks AS 'Subject Level Marks',
    planRank.grade AS 'Subject Grade',
    planRank.obtainedMarks AS 'Percentage',
    planRank.status AS 'Result Status',
    result.levelOnePrintName AS 'Type',
    typeRank.effectiveMarks AS 'Type Marks',
    typeRank.grade AS 'Type Grade',
    typeRank.status AS 'Type Result Status',
    result.levelTwoPrintName AS 'Sub Type',
    subTypeRank.effectiveMarks AS 'Sub Type Marks',
    subTypeRank.grade AS 'Sub Type Grade',
    subTypeRank.status AS 'Sub Type Result Status',
    result.levelThreePrintName AS 'Method',
    result.effectiveMarks AS 'Method Marks',
    result.grade AS 'Method Grade',
    result.status AS 'Method Result Status',
    CASE
        WHEN evntDetail.eventName IS NULL THEN evnt.detailSequenceNumber
        WHEN evntDetail.eventName IS NOT NULL THEN evntDetail.eventName
        ELSE NULL
    END AS 'Event',
    eventMarks.effectiveMarks AS 'Event Marks',
    eventMarks.finalGrade AS 'Event Grade'
FROM
    marksheet AS result
        INNER JOIN
    admission AS admission ON admission.id = result.admissionId
        INNER JOIN
    users AS usr ON usr.id = result.studentId
        INNER JOIN
    academy_location AS al ON al.id = admission.academyLocationId
        INNER JOIN
    programs AS prgm ON prgm.id = result.programId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    program_group AS pg ON pg.id = prgm.programGroupId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    program_category AS pc ON pc.id = prgm.programCategoryId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    courses AS course ON course.id = result.courseId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    course_category AS cc ON cc.id = course.courseCategoryId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    program_batch_course_param AS param ON result.courseVariantId = param.courseVarientId
        AND result.periodId = param.progBatchPeriodConfigId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    prog_batch_course_faculty AS pbcf ON pbcf.progBatchCourseParamId = param.id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    users AS fac ON fac.id = pbcf.facultyId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    evaluation_plan_rank AS planRank ON result.admissionId = planRank.admissionId
        AND (result.courseVariantId = planRank.courseVariantId
        OR planRank.courseVariantId IS NULL)
        AND result.sectionId = planRank.sectionId
        AND result.periodId = planRank.periodId
        AND result.evaluationPlanId = planRank.evaluationPlanId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    evaluation_plan_level_one_rank AS typeRank ON result.admissionId = typeRank.admissionId
        AND (result.courseVariantId = typeRank.courseVariantId
        OR typeRank.courseVariantId IS NULL)
        AND result.periodId = typeRank.periodId
        AND result.sectionId = typeRank.sectionId
        AND result.evaluationPlanLevelOneId = typeRank.evaluationPlanLevelOneId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    evaluation_plan_level_two_rank AS subTypeRank ON result.admissionId = subTypeRank.admissionId
        AND (result.courseVariantId = subTypeRank.courseVariantId)
        AND result.periodId = subTypeRank.periodId
        AND result.sectionId = subTypeRank.sectionId
        AND result.evaluationPlanLevelTwoId = subTypeRank.evaluationPlanLevelTwoId
        INNER JOIN
    eval_seq_detail AS evnt ON result.evaluationPlanThreeId = evnt.evalSequenceId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    examination_result AS eventMarks ON result.admissionId = eventMarks.admissionId
        AND (result.courseVariantId = eventMarks.courseVariantId
        OR eventMarks.courseVariantId IS NULL)
        AND result.sectionId = eventMarks.sectionId
        AND result.periodId = eventMarks.periodId
        AND evnt.id = eventMarks.evaluationDetailSequenceId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    evaluation_type_course typeCourse ON eventMarks.courseVariantId = typeCourse.courseVariantId
        AND eventMarks.periodId = typeCourse.periodId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    exam_event_detail evntDetail ON eventMarks.evaluationDetailSequenceId = evntDetail.eventId
        AND evntDetail.evaluationTypeCourseId = typeCourse.id
WHERE
    eventMarks.examResultStatus IS NOT NULL
        AND result.evaluationPlanId IS NOT NULL
        AND result.evaluationPlanLevelOneId IS NOT NULL
        AND result.evaluationPlanLevelTwoId IS NOT NULL
        AND result.evaluationPlanThreeId IS NOT NULL;
```

In tables marksheet = '740119' and examination_result = '4891575' approx records.
when I execute query then it will take around 10 min and also show time out error, as data-set is large.

I applied indexes on table's for performance but still Query take lots of time.

I applied Explain on Query to check status -

[image]

Comment: _show time out error, as data-set is large_ Can we see the actual error messge

Comment: Sure I will update you with Screen shots, mean while it show connection lost and when I applied limit with around 2000 data then it takes 1 min for 2000 records.

Comment: Can you please review the shared query and help me for optimization, it will really help me.

Below are the Error I got while executed Query -  
Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Comment: One observation...

      `"LEFT 
        JOIN examination_result eventMarks...
       WHERE eventMarks.examResultStatus IS NOT NULL"`
       
...would appear to be functionally identical to...

       `"JOIN examination_result eventMarks..."`

Comment: According to the `EXPLAIN` there might be about a million rows in the result.  How many do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Add the keyword "STRAIGHT_JOIN" to you query.  It looks like you have everything in proper logical alignment.  You are querying from the main table and joining to all the lookup tables secondary.  MySQL sometimes tries to optimize based on table row sizes and will look at a smaller table as a more beneficial path and can choke.

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN (rest of query)
```

Tells MySQL to do the query in the order you provided, don't think for me.

Now, that said, you don't really have a WHERE clause that may be taking advantage of an index.  To prevent the need of having to go to every data page for the records, if you have an index on the where clauses, the engine can pre-qualify those records where not null via the index.  Assuming that each evaluation plan is an integer (numeric) based "ID" value, I would add an index on

```
( evaluationPlanId, evaluationPlanLevelOneId, evaluationPlanLevelTwoId, evaluationPlanThreeId )
```

Comment: I saw table it is already indexed with ( evaluationPlanId, evaluationPlanLevelOneId, evaluationPlanLevelTwoId, evaluationPlanThreeId ) id's.
I also tried STRAIGHT_JOIN on Query but there is no impact on Query it showing same error..